# Does anyones knows if you can make a parameter in services.yaml dynamic

Tags: symfony, syntax, yaml

In a Symfony project, I add different directories of images. I want to know if it's possible to add only one dynamic directory that changes depending on the type of image (logo, conception, proposition, etc) that I'm using.

I have this:

```
parameters:
    images_directory: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/admin/assets/images/imagesUpload'
    avatar_directory: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/admin/assets/images/users'
    vitrine_directory: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/vitrine/images/imagesUpload'
    vitrine_directory_carousel: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/vitrine/images/imagesUpload/carousel'
    vitrine_directory_proposition: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/vitrine/images/imagesUpload/proposition'
    vitrine_directory_conception: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/vitrine/images/imagesUpload/conception'
    vitrine_directory_logo: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/vitrine/images/imagesUpload/logo'
    vitrine_directory_contact: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/vitrine/images/imagesUpload/contact'
```

And I want something that can group all the directories in one dynamic directory.

Comment: By using environment variable in your .env file and call it in your parameters file.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, but I'm really new in Symfony, do you think you could give me an example or something more to guide me

Comment: Of course :). Here's my services.yaml : https://github.com/HamHamFonFon/deep-space-objects/blob/master/config/services.yaml where are my parameters (i don't have parameters.yml yet), and all parametres with `%env(MY_PARAMETER)%` are declared in .env file or as environnment variable